# How to migrate all the data of an sqlite database to cockroachdb (for a django project)

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, cockroachdb

I created a Django application and deployed it for testing purposes. I now have data which i would not like to lose, but i want to use cockroachDB for storing the web-app data. The SQLite database is the one django creates automatically while applying migrations. Is there a way to move all that data to my cockroachDB cluster? I will be using cockroachDB for my database.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the [settings.py in your django app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/) to use a different database.

For example, one can use the [dj_database_url module to set up a connection with cockroachDB](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/build-a-python-app-with-cockroachdb-django.html?filters=local#step-5-configure-the-database-connection).

Comment: But if i already have a database, will changing my DB settings in this manner preserve all the data? Won't i use all my existing data if i do it this way?

Comment: Oh you are trying to migrate your existing database to cockroachDB? Then I would suggest seeing the SQLite docs for how to export your data. And then you could import that data into cockroachDB (see https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/migration-overview.html).